# Changes not staging during Python subprocess call of empty commit

Tags: python, git, subprocess, git-commit, git-add

At the end of a Python program I have:

```
subprocess.call(["git", "add", "."], shell=True)
subprocess.call(["git", "commit", "-m", "'{}'".format("commit message"), "--allow-empty"], shell=True)
```

This commit has no changes from the previous commit besides the commit message, hence the `--allow-empty`.

When I run `git status` in my repository, I get that all of the files are not staged for commit (and I cannot re-base because of this).

However, if I comment those two lines out, run the program again, and manually run in shell once the program is finished:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
```

The files are all added and committed and I am able to re-base successfully.

Even when adding another two subprocess `git add` and `git commit` commands, with or without `--allow-empty` to the end of the program, the only way to actually add and commit the files is manually through a shell.

Am I missing something here? Shouldn't the subprocess hypothetically be doing the exact same thing as the shell commands?

Comment: The first question I would look into is: *what is the current working directory at the time of the `subprocess.call` calls?* There are more, but that's a good first one to consider, I think. You might also try spawning an interactive shell at that point, which will let you investigate other settings as well.

Comment: don't add quotes when passing command as list of args: try `subprocess.call(["git", "commit", "-m", "commit message", "--allow-empty"], shell=True)`. Also try without `shell=True`, because if it works without, well, it's one less thing to worry about

Comment: also replace `call` by `check_call` so the program crashes if something goes wrong instead of failing silently

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["git","commit","."],shell=True);
p.terminate();
```